# Local Storage value not storing on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, submit

Not sure why this isn't working, but I have a form that I'm trying to store the input value of email into `localStorage`. But I also have it mixed in with some email validation, so I'm not sure if that could be causing it to fail and not store within the browser?

Here's what I have:

```
  $( "#loginform" ).submit(function(e) {
    var vaild_email = $('#loginform input[name=log]').val();
    if( /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(valid_email) ){
      localStorage.setItem("email", valid_email);
      return true;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault(e);
    }
  });
```

Yeah, not sure if I'm missing something or just going about this all wrong?

Comment: How have you determined this is failing? Are you certain the logic flows in to the right condition? Have you checked the console to see if the value is actually set? Where and how are you trying to retrieve the value?

Comment: In chrome, open developer tools -> Application -> Local Storage, and see if you see there the "email" key.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I'm checking in chrome dev tools under the application tab -> Local Storage and nothing is being set for that key.

Comment: And what of my other suggestions? Are you sure the logic is going in the truthy condition? It would help a lot if you actually showed a working example of the problem in a snippet

Comment: Side note, correct me if I'm wrong, but using {2,} makes the preceding + before them unnecessary?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I'm sorry, but I don't really get what you are saying as far as a "truthful" condition. Overall, it's a login form that I'm trying to do two things; 1.) Check to see if the email is valid 2.) store the email into local storage so I can pull that value back out when the page redirects to "success" page. I guess I can strip out the email validation and try to see if it stores the value outright. That way I'll know if the validation is causing the issue.

Comment: @Taplar - Possibly. That was a validation script that someone suggested from SO. If there is a better solution for handling email validation, I'm all for it.

Comment: Email validation through regex is a pretty hot button topic.  So no comment from me there, :D

Comment: @Taplar - Haha! Fair enough!

Comment: FWIW - I've tested this without the form validation and it's still not storing. So something else is at play here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so apparently, I'm running off of very little sleep because the root of all of these issues is I had misspelled my variable of `valid_email`.

Once I corrected that, everything is fine now.

Also worth noting that you cannot have a space between `key` and `item`.

Should be something like this:
`localStorage.setItem("email",valid_email);`

Not this:
`localStorage.setItem("email", valid_email);`

I'm gonna take a nap now.